# How do I transfer a voice file from a voice recorder to the computer and create a file for dropbox so I can share it?

Tags: audio-recording

I have a Olympus voice recorder.  I can plug in the recorder into the computer and hit play on my recorder and listen to it through the mike.  What is the best or easiest way to create some sort of audio file on the computer so it can be shared through dropbox?

Comment: Search the manual and help webpages for your Olympus voice recorder, if it's not too old it could have a way to transfer audio files to your computer easily

Comment: Transfer the data file to your computer and upload it to Dropbox I assume you mean you have a digital voice recorder and connect it to your computer over USB

Comment: This question is confusing you can't listen to audio over microphone at least without modifying the microphone.

Answer (score 0):

If your sound card supports it you can record using the line in on your computer. Audacity is a good free program for recording audio. Once you have Audacity installed select the appropriate recording device then record your audio. You can then export it to an mp3 file and share it on Dropbox.